# Cursor Won't Move - ASUS C300

Tags: drivers, kernel, touchpad, asus

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my ASUS C300m Chromebook, completely replacing Chrome OS. It has worked wonderfully except for one tiny little problem. Ever since I updated to the latest kernel, the cursor won't respond to my track pad. Also I noticed that there are no real options in the mouse settings other than speed, so I think maybe the Master Driver may not be functioning correctly.

Any help would be awesome, thank you Ubuntu Community!

```
lspci -k
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series SoC Transaction Register (rev 0e)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 0f31
    Kernel driver in use: iosf_mbi_pci
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Graphics & Display (rev 0e)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Graphics & Display
    Kernel driver in use: i915
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series USB xHCI (rev 0e)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series USB xHCI
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
00:1a.0 Encryption controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Trusted Execution Engine (rev 0e)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series High Definition Audio Controller (rev 0e)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series High Definition Audio Controller
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor E3800 Series PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 0e)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Power Control Unit (rev 0e)
    Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich
01:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 6b)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi


 Virtual core pointer                       id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Elan Touchpad                             id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB2.0 UVC HD Webcam                      id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Comment: What do you call "the latest kernel"? Is at an Ubuntu kernel or a mainline one?

Comment: 4.2.0-27-generic

Comment: How did you install it? Maybe you did not install `linux-image-extra`?

Comment: And the latest is 4.2.0-30

Comment: I used the auto-update feature built into Ubuntu.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `xinput` terminal command. If you also upgraded graphical stack, you could do it wrong.

Comment: So was it initially 14.04.4? 4.2.0-27 was there already without any updates.

Comment: Well initially, I just reverted back to -27 until I can figure this out. Sorry, I should have said that. It was -30 after the update

Comment: So with -27 it worked OK? I looks that -30 has lots of bugs. It should be reported to launchpad.

Comment: Yes, the whole system works awesome with -27, but I don't know how to look up what changed in -30

Comment: It is easy to lookup in git, but you'd better install -30 and run `ubuntu-bug linux`, then follow directions and describe the problem.

Comment: Ah, thank you. Honestly, it's been about 3 years since I've used Ubuntu. I've forgotten about a lot of the resources.

Comment: http://kernel.ubuntu.com/git/ubuntu/ubuntu-wily.git The bugs started from -28, it was never released, but they did not fix it in -30.

Comment: It could be this commit http://kernel.ubuntu.com/git/ubuntu/ubuntu-wily.git/commit/drivers/input?id=8c50ca7fa1c4be4378ab8fd5824b8f4a9a29c91d

Comment: So basically I shouldn't update. I should watch the logs until someone says it's fixed? That's cool, I can do that. I only wish I had the coding prowess to help fix it myself, but I have no knowledge outside of HTML, which I am told isn't actually coding. :)

Comment: You'd better report the bug. Or noone will ever fix it.

Comment: I'll report it. Working on that right now. Thank you very much sir!

Comment: I submitted a bug report and gosh they're fast! I got an email a day later telling me to send them some more data and that they will be handling the bug very shortly. Also I will post and answer to my own question hopefully soon because the guy who emailed me said he's looking for a work around until they get it fixed in the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

So, the answer to this question. It appears that the Linux Kernel drops and adds support for the ASUS C300 Chromebook periodically. The Kernels that I know work with this machine are 4.2.0-34, 4.2.0-45. From my conversations with different contributors, the Kernel should support the touchpad hardware from now on.